# Favorite questions are not anymore highlighted on SO

Tags: discussion, support, bookmarks

Sometime this morning, all of a sudden questions tagged with any of my favorite tags on SO stopped being highlighted.

[image]

The marked tags are among my favorites so these posts should be higlighted.

Do others see this as well? Is this a planned change, or something weird is going on? I could not find any info about this on the blog or on here.

I am using Firefox 3.6.13 on WinXP.

#### Update

Soon after posting this, I noticed more weird behaviour:

- the tag edit button does not appear anymore when I hover next to tags in questions,
- the [Tag Favorites and Tag Subscriptions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/tag-favorites-and-tag-subscriptions/) tooltip does not appear anymore,
- Ctrl+K does not work anymore in the editor,
- the notification about receiving a new badge does not appear anymore (the page is shifted down, but only a blank space appears without any text).

These might be connected to the above phenomenon. Apparently some sort of script blocking? Since noone else is complaining loudly, this might be a quirk in my local environment (possibly some firewall/proxy issue?).

#### Update 2

After pressing Shift+Refresh on the SO page, the highlighting reappeared at once, also the other issues seems to have disappeared. So apparently it was some local problem indeed (some broken data in the cache?).

Comment: Weird.  This is `no-repro` for me and I'm on the same version of Firefox and WinXP Pro.

Comment: It intermittently happened to me recently as well. FF 3.6.13, Win7.

Comment: @Bill I've got a similar problem. In my case nor favorite questions nor source code are being highlighted. However it happens from time to time and not always. When it happens my browser shows that it's still loading the page. So it seems that some javascript can't connect to a server or css can't be loaded. Opera, Mac.

Comment: @ssmir, I have seen this many times - the text content is displayed without highlighting, and the browser is still loading the page. It often shows a message on the status bar like "Connecting to sstatic.net" (I am not sure though about the exact server name). Then after several seconds, the page is finally loaded and highlighting appears.

Comment: éter yes but in my case it just hangs and doesn't load anymore. So to be able to use hyperlinks on the page I have to stop the loading of the page. However the problem doesn't appear in the Firefox

Answer (score 1):

I might be taking a wild guess here but I think jQuery was not loading correctly.